# Выбрать все и выбрать отдельную колонку как (SQL)

Tags: select, sql

Такой вопрос: Мне нужно сделать выборку из бд всех полей, но некоторые поля нужно выбрать назначив им другое имя на выходе (SELECT title AS title_en)
Как это можно реализовать, чтобы вручную не писать имена всех выбираемых полей?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *,title AS title_en FROM table
```

Comment: блин я так пробовал, фишка для многоязычности, и у меня и в русс и в англ поле были одинаковые названия, вот думал что не работает ) спасибо.

Comment: Мне подобный запрос (**`SELECT *, COUNT(id) as total ... LIMIT 15`**) вернул две записи, проверьте на всякий случай.

Comment: не понял комментарий :) так что нужно то?

Comment: scor вроде все работает, спасибо.
sh4dow у меня все ок вроде.

Comment: проверил, должно работать

Answer (score 2):

```
$fields = array(
  'name1' => '',
  'name2' => '',
  'name3' => 'name_lol',
  'name4' => 'lol',
  );
$f = array();
foreach ($fields as $name => $alias) 
  $f []= (!empty($alias)) ? "`$name` AS `$alias`" : "`$name`";
$q = 'SELECT '.implode(', ', $f).' FROM my_table LIMIT 1';
die(var_dump($q));
```

Answer (score 2):

Если есть, например, таблица T(a,b,c), то согласно стандарту переименовать столбцы можно так:

```
select * from (
select * from T) as X(a1,b1,c1)
```

Работает в MSSQL и PostgreSQL.